# Using JavaScript split to encompass words, punctuation with span but ignore HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I know there are topics that cover almost the same subject but I couldn't find one that would help me achieve what I need.

So I have some text with words, punctuation, and HTML, say

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper elit efficitur tempus sagittis. Vivamus at eros — quis velit ornare consequat. Vestibulum suscipit erat enim; sed bibendum augue interdum at.</p>
<p>Sed vulputate ipsum id ullamcorper vehicula. Ut ac ornare risus, id vehicula justo. Quisque pretium, lectus "et rutrum fermentum", leo mauris interdum eros, nec blandit nibh dolor nec enim.</p>
```

What I'd like to do is encompass each word and punctuation mark with a `<span>` element while ignoring and keeping intact the HTML tags. I'd need to encompass *every* punctuation mark, even if they are right next to each other or a word.

So the output would be something like

```
<p><span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>sit</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span><span>,</span> (etc...)
```

So far I've managed to split by whitespace and encompass the result with `<span>`, but the HTML tags and punctuation give a headache. :P

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I've used so far (the text to be split is, as you can see, in a `div`element with `id=textarea`:

```
$('#textarea').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html().split(" "),
        len = text.length,
        result = []; 

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        result[i] = '<span class="clickable">' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    $(this).html(result.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: What code did you use to wrap the words and punctuation?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? If so you can do it fairly easily using `.text()` to work around the tags and syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/r6dz97ud/

```
$("p").each(function(i, p) {
    var words = $(p).text()
    $(p).html("")
    $(words.split(" ")).each(function(j, word) {
        var span = $("<span></span>")
        span.html(word)
        $(p).append(span).append("&nbsp;")
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, that would work with only `<p>` elements, could it be possible to make it apply to _any_ HTML tags?

Comment: And it only encompasses punctuation marks surrounded by white spaces on both sides. I'd need it to encompass _every_ punctuation mark, even if they are right next to each other or a word.

Comment: yep, you could extend these ideas to make all that work - the main thing I wanted to show you was using the `text()` method to pull out the words to make the initial parsing easier.

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean! I'll try this with the `children` selector!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution to perform this on any html string value:

```
var tagsexpr = "(\\<\\w+\\>)|(\\<\\/\\w+\\>)";
var wordexpr = "[^\\<?\\/|>| ]\\w+";
var puncexpr = "[\\.,\\?\\!]";

function wrap(text) {
  var tags = text.match(new RegExp(tagsexpr, 'g'));
  var words = text.match(new RegExp(wordexpr + '|' + puncexpr, 'g'));

  return tags[0] + words.reduce(function (base, curr, indx) {
    return (new RegExp(puncexpr, 'g')).test(words[indx + 1]) ? 
      base + '<span>' + words[indx] + '</span>' : base + '<span>' + words[indx] + '</span> ';
  }, '').trim() + tags[1];
}

console.log(wrap('<p>hello from the matrix.</p>'));
// => "<p><span>hello</span> <span>from</span> <span>the</span> <span>matrix</span><span>.</span></p>"
```

Comment: Yes! Nearly there! :D 

I'm in over my head here, but I'd like to add a couple of things to the list of punctuation marks, like doublequote and apostrophe, so I did this:

`var puncexpr = "[\\.,\\'\\;\\–\\—\\?\\!";
puncexpr += '\\"]';`

But if a quote is right before a word, they get wrapped into a single `<span>`: "hey" --> `<span>"hey</span><span>"</span>`